# Escape dollar sign in string by shell script

Tags: bash, shell

Suppose I have a script named dd.sh, and I run it like this

```
./dd.sh sample$name.mp4
```

So `$1` is the string `sample$name.mp4`.

```
echo '$1' // shows $1

echo "$1" // shows "sample.mp4"; want "sample$name.mp4"
```

Then how to process `$1` that I can detect whether there is a dollar sign in parameter `$1`

I want to process the string to `sample\$name.mp4` or just detect whether there is a dollar sign in parameter `$filename`

Comment: Assign it in single quotes. `filename='sample$name.mp4'`

Comment: I got this variable as a parameter $1, so I can't quote it before I assign it to $filename

Comment: ``filename="sample\$name.mp4"`` this will print ``sample$name.mp4`` is this what you want?

Comment: @biubiubiu What are you talking about, post your actual data if this isn't it.

Comment: what do you want to do with this? I mean, do you need to pass the string `sample$name.mp4` or, instead, have a string on the form `sample`+ value of `$name` + `.mp4`?

Comment: @fedorqui I need to passing a string may contain $ to a shell script, I want to know how to detect in script whether the string contain $ or not

Comment: Well this is a different question. Regarding passing a string with a `$`, follow @123 's suggestion and just single quote it: `./your_script.sh 'your$var'`. Note you have to use single quotes, because double quotes will expand `$var`. Regarding the other question, well... it's another question.

Answer (score 157):

As you know, a dollar sign marks a variable. You have to take it into account when you are typing it.

You can escape the dollar

```
./dd.sh "sample\$name.mp4"
```

or just type it with single quotes

```
./dd.sh 'sample$name.mp4'
```

---

To check if there is a dollar sign in a variable, do

```
[[ $variable == *\$* ]] && echo 'I HAZ A DOLAR!!!' || echo 'MEH'
```

Comment: I know this, but when I passing it as a parameter, I must possess $1 with quote like "sample\$name.mp4"

Comment: This worked for me, but because it was inside quotes I had to escape the escape: `alias cacheoff="echo \"\\\$config['cache_off'] = 'yes';\" >> config.php`

Comment: The `$` was already inside single quotes and still needed to be escaped.

Comment: @gone If you use *find* in *bash* then there's no difference. What prohibits you from using single quotes?

Comment: (Comment before @pacholik answered): What if you're using `find` and you don't have the option to type single quotes? (Additional Information after @pacholik, responsed.):
In my case, a parent script using find was passing in the file name as `"{}"` which was causing my child script to receive the file name with the $ already interpolated.  Switching the parent to use `'{}'` fixed that, and then `newName=$(echo ${name/$/-})` did the trick in the child script.

Answer (score 22):

One option:

```sh
# Replace occurrences of $ with \$ to prevent variable substitution:
filename="${filename//$/\\$}"
```

I just realized my prompt was showing `foo` rather than `foo$bar$baz` as the name of the current branch. `foo$bar$baz` was getting assigned to `PS1` and `$bar` and `$baz` were then expanded. Escaping the dollar signs before including the branch name in `PS1` prevents unwanted expansions.

Comment: awesome trick! I'm familiar with bash, even knew about variable defaults but not familiar with trick you described. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Demo:

Evidently, the single quotes `'` results in no interpolation of enclosing characters.

```
cat > test.sh
echo '$1'
echo "$1"

% ./test.sh hello
$1
hello

% ./test.sh hello$world
$1
hello

% ./test.sh hello\$world
$1
hello$world      << Looks as expected

% ./test.sh 'hello\$world'
$1
hello\$world

% ./test.sh "hello\$world"
$1
hello$world      << Looks as expected
```

Answer (score 5):

Your issue is not with the `echo` but with the assignment to `$filename`.

You say

```
filename="sample$name.mp4"
```

This will interpolate the string, which means expanding the variable `$name`.  This will result in `$filename` having the value `sample.mp4` (since `$name` is presumably undefined, which means it expands to an empty string)

Instead, use single quotes in the assignment:

```
filename='sample$name.mp4'
```

`echo "$filename"` will now result in the expected `sample$name.mp4`. Obviously, `echo '$filename'` will still just print `$filename` because of the single quotes.

Answer (score 3):

If your question is:

> Then how to process $1 that I can detect whether there is a dollar
>   sign in parameter $1

You can try this:

```
if [[ $1 == *'$'* ]]
then
   echo '$ was found'
else
   echo '$ was not found'
fi
```

**Output:**

```
$ ./dd.sh 'sample$name.mp4'  // prints $ was found
$ ./dd.sh 'samplename.mp4'  // prints $ was not found
```

Answer (score 3):

For example you have **.env** file with variables and password for postgres DB. As you know password should be urlencoded course **%** sing in password. So we have a problem here. Because BASH ignore **$** and we get always wrong password for encode.

## .env file

```
    DB_NAME=sone_db
    DB_PASS=A1$Bb%!Y$  # with dollar signs
    ...
```

## bash script

```
    #!/bin/bash
    PSQL_COMMAND="DROP schema public CASCADE;"
    PSQL_COMMAND+="CREATE schema public;"

    set -o allexport
    # set source file and get access to all variables in .env
    source /path/.env

    ENCODED_PASS=$(python -c "from urllib.parse import quote; print(quote('$DB_PASS'))");
    psql postgres://$DB_USER:$ENCODED_PASS@$DB_HOST:5432/$DB_NAME -c "$PSQL_COMMAND"

    echo $DB_PASS   # returns A1%!Y$
    echo '$DB_PASS' # returns $DB_PASS
    echo "$DB_PASS" # returns A1%!Y$

    # disables variables
    set +o allexport

    # Wont work because BASH find $ sing in string and think that is variable, 
    so in first and last echo missed part $Bb%
```

To resolve this you need in *.env* file escape string in single quote

```
    ...
    DB_PASS='A1$Bb%!Y$' 
    ...
```