# How to source value with $ char in bash

Tags: bash, escaping

I have a file with some vars.

```
- myvarfile - 
host="localhost"
port="8080"
user="john"
pass="neoj$vae"
```

When I source this file into a bash script obviously pass has value "noej", cutting "$vae".
How can I get the full string?

NOTE: pass value is generated randomic so I don't know which chars is in it.
Thanks.

Comment: you have to have something that set's the value of `$vae` that gets executed before you source your `myvarfile`. I just tested, once I had executed `vae=ABC`, then sourcing your file, and `echo $pass` produced `neojABC`. Good luck.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Escape dollar sign in string by shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37876778/escape-dollar-sign-in-string-by-shell-script)

Comment: Strictly speaking, nothing is being cut. `$vae` is being *replaced* by the current value of the variable `vae`, which happens to be empty.

Comment: If you mean the *literal* value including the dollar sign as a character in the password, use SINGLE quotes.

Answer (score 5):

Read the bash manual on the different types of quote characters

```
pass="neoj$vae"
echo $pass
neoj
pass='neoj$vae'
echo $pass
neoj$vae
```

Comment: This looks like the most likely correct answer, given an unclear (IMHO) question. Good luck to all.

Answer (score 2):

Use single quote marks like `pass='neoj$vae'`