# Is there a sleep, pause, timeout or wait command for SnowSQL?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, ksh

I have a linux script that runs SnowSQL where two files are created and placed in a particular folder. Due to a downstream process, there needs to be a delay between the time the first and second files are placed in the folder. (I prefer not to use two separate ksh scripts.)

This creates/places both files in the destination folder at the same time:

get ${outFileNm} file://${inDir}/;

get ${outFileNm2} file://${inDir}/;

====================

If SnowSQL supports something like this, I *believe* the command would be placed here in **bold**:

get ${outFileNm} file://${inDir}/;

**<enter sleep/pause/timeout/wait command here>**

get ${outFileNm2} file://${inDir}/;

Comment: Can you add any details about why you do not what in done in your shell script?

Comment: It is not that I don't want to do it in the shell script it is that I don't want to have to run two scripts to accomplish this. That was was why I was thinking a pause would work. The much smaller File 1 needs to be sent a few minutes before File 2 as File 2 is dependent on File 1 and the order of processing in the downstream server is first come first serve.

Comment: @SimeonPilgrim, are you suggesting having two separate SnowSQL sessions within the same script? That might work. Run the File 1 session and send the file. THEN system wait. THEN run SnowSQL session 2. Is this what you were thinking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out! Even though the command was within SnowSQL, the ksh script was trying to treat $wait as a Linux variable. By adding a backslash in front of $wait, we are telling the script to treat $ as a literal $ sign. This works:

get ${outFileNm} file://${inDir}/;

```
call system\$wait(60);
```

get ${outFileNm2} file://${inDir}/;

Thanks to all who commented.

Answer (score 3):

There is a system function called `system$wait`.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/system_wait.html

```
select system$wait(5);
```

| SYSTEM$WAIT(5) |
| --- |
| waited 5 seconds |

Comment: Thank you, Greg. Unfortunately, this doesn't work. I get this error:  "Unknown function SYSTEM" when doing this in my ksh:

get ${outFileNm} file://${inDir}/;
select system$wait(30);
get ${outFileNm2} file://${inDir}/;

Comment: KornShell treats a dollar sign as a variable identifier. You can try wrapping it in quotes or escaping it as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37876778/escape-dollar-sign-in-string-by-shell-script

Answer (score 0):

so the [command reference](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/snowsql-use.html#commands-reference) defines a [pause](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/snowsql-use.html#pause)

> !pause
>
> Pause running queries. Press the return key to continue.

Which if you wrapped the snowsql in something like expect, then could watch for and wait in that, and then provide the input.

But it really does seem like and out of channel wait, in the ksh script makes much more sense

Or can you do something via the [system](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/snowsql-use.html#system) that delays for the required time?